# Problems with the version of Expo 48, Undefined is not a function, React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I have a fully functional application and I uploaded it to the Play Store with Expo 46 but when trying to upload an update it asked me to upload the sdk to 48 and I did but the application that worked before now no longer works, I tried many ways and none of them work I tried with sdk 47 and my application worked again does anyone know what happens with sdk 48 and its new Hermes engine, my application tries to upload information to FIRESTORE and every time I do it with Expo 48 I get an error, undefined is not a function, in the catch. I leave my package.json the only thing that changes is the version of React, React Native and Expo.

```
 "expo": "~48.0.18",
 "react": "18.2.0",
 "react-native": "0.71.8",
```

```
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.12",
    "expo": "~47.0.0",
    "expo-av": "13.0.3",
    "expo-camera": "13.1.0",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "2.3.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "14.0.2",
    "expo-leaflet": "1.0.3",
    "expo-location": "15.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "firebase": "9.7.0",
    "formik": "2.4.2",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "luxon": "3.3.0",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-dropdown-select-list": "2.0.4",
    "react-native-elements": "3.4.3",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "1.8.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.5",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.18.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "2.1.6",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.0",
    "uuid": "9.0.0",
    "yup": "1.2.0"
```

Expo 48 Hermes engine I get an error, undefined is not a function

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you upgrade your Expo SDK, you have to follow the instructions published on [blog.expo.dev](https://blog.expo.dev) to make it all work.

Here's the instructions to pass from v46 to v47: [Expo SDK 47](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-47-a0f6f5c038af)
Here's the instructions to pass from v47 to v48: [Expo SDK 48](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-48-ccb8302e231)